# OpenCV The contour area larger than, eg. 200px

Tags: opencv

I use the background substraction to detect hand. http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html
Then I would like to outline just a hand. To get rid of imperfections from the background.
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html
But the method is all the contours. I would like to alb contoured those elements which have larger area than, for example. 200px.  How to do it? There is a better method to obtain the same hand in the picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two parameters of contour from which you can extract the [info of contour](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html) 
1.contourArea
2.arcLength

Another way of focus only on hand is Training haar cascade for hand detection.
Please refer to the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542344/hand-detection-opencv) ask before.